Unable to open WCF Client on UTM Virtual Machine with an ARM Macbook
I am getting an error when I try to use a WCF client through Visual Studio Community on a virtual machine.  I have a Windows VM on UTM that I am using the Windows ARM ISO on.  However, when I try to open a service in browser, I get an error as such: Web client error.  I am also getting another error when I try to open a downloaded file, where it says IIS Express is unable to be opened.
I have tried deleting the IIS folder and redoing it. I have also enabled the NET framework through Windows.  I am not sure what else I could do.
Edit (Error Message in text):
Server Error in '/' Application.
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {A9E69610-B80D-11D0-B9B9-00A0C922E750} failed due to the following error: 8004015
Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID (A9E69610-B80D-11D0-B9B9-00A0C922E750) failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
(REGDBLE_CLASSNOTREG)).
Source Error:
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Stack Trace:
[COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {A969610-B80D-11D0-B9B9-00A0C922E750} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not
System.Runtime-AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +848
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +276
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar) +248
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +200

Please include error messages as text in your post, not as images.

Fixed, error message is included as text.
